# Alias in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, alias

I have been looking at pyspark code recently and I see `alias` very often. But I do not really 
understand how it is used and what it means. So I was wondering if someone could explain how it works
in the two examples below.

```
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.Date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).alias('dt_col'))

df.select([count(when(isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias is inherited from `SQL` syntax. That's a way to rename a variable within a query (e.g. a `select`). It avoids creating a temporary name you don't choose and having to rename the variable afterwards with something like `withColumnRenamed`.

For instance,

```py
df.select([count(when(isnan(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

Ensures that the result of the count operation will return a new variable with the same name than in `df` object. Otherwise you would end-up with variables named `count(col1)`... where `col1` is the initial variable name.

Aliasing is very useful when performing aggregations.

On the same way,

```py
df.select(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.Date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).alias('dt_col'))
```

is a concise way to do:

```py
df.withColumn('dt_col', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.Date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).select('dt_col')
```